# simplify getting coordinates from cv2.findContours

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop

I'm currently working with opencv 3.4 and getting the contours as a list of coordinates from a binary image. My code looks like the following:

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
list_of_contours= []
for contour in contours:         
    list_of_contours.append(list(map(tuple, (coord[0] for coord in contour))))
```

It is working as intended but I'm curious if the loop in `list(map(tuple, (c[0] for c in contour)))` could be avoided and/or is it even reasonable to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
xcnts = np.vstack((x.reshape(-1,2) for x in cnts))
print(xcnts.shape)
```

It return `(698, 2)` for this image (from [opencv - plot contours in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212239/opencv-plot-contours-in-an-image)):

[image]