# opencv - plot contours in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to draw contour around an image. I can see that contours being found but I am not able to draw the outline. The color of the contour seem to be either of the two (black and white) colors.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
%matplotlib inline
im = io.imread('http://matlabtricks.com/images/post-35/man.png')
plt.imshow(im)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(imgray)

#Contoured image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
c_img = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(c_img)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to draw on the original image, not on the one returned from `findContuors()`. The following works.

```
# Contoured image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
for contour in contours:
   cv2.drawContours(im, contour, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

This is my result:

[image]

---

```
## Read and convert 
img = io.imread('http://matlabtricks.com/images/post-35/man.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## Find outer contours 
_, cnts, _= cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

## Draw 
canvas = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.drawContours(canvas , contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

plt.imshow(canvas)
```